# Terraform TGW VPC Attachment Data Source filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to get `TGW VPC Attachment` `data source` using a `vpc_owner_id` filter.

I tried:

```
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "attach" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-owner-id"
    values = ["543265436543"]
}
}
```

and

```
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "attach" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc_owner_id"
    values = ["543265436543"]
}
}
```

and

```
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "attach" {
  filter {
    name = "resource-owner-id"
    values = ["543265436543"]
}
}
```

I get that the `Value for the parameter Filter is invalid.`
One of the attributes of the `TGW VPC Attachment` is `vpc_owner_id`.

Is that possible to get this `data source` using `vpc owner id` `Filter`?

Comment: I developed my own custom data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **no filters** `vpc_owner_id` nor `vpc-owner-id`. The only valid one is `resource-owner-id`. For the list of valid filters please refer to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTransitGatewayAttachments.html).

If any of the given filters does not suit you, you have to **develop your own** [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source).

Comment: "resource-owner-id" isn't working for me either.  Getting "InvalidParameterValue".
This is the correct link to the doc for VPC attachments:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTransitGatewayVpcAttachments.html